# Photoshop Pixelated edges when rotating

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel

[image: 4 frames of arm rotation]

Hello there,

I have been working on a game lately and have little experience with photoshop. As I am doing animation of the frame in photoshop which has been fine I have all of a sudden come across a massive problem. All of a sudden when I rotate things while animating. (In this case an arm) the pixels get all messed up. In the picture you can see 4 frames. The first three I did a few weeks ago and 4th I did just now to show the effect that is happening with the pixels getting all messed up.

I have tried to change the Image interpolation but to no avail. People only post saying that isnt possible to have good pixel rotations but this is obviously not true as the first 3 frames should illustrate. I am quite certain that I have disabled something by mistake that has caused this but have too little experience to know what I have done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that I was able to correct this issue with image interpolation I do not for the life of me know why it was not working the first time I tried that.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a raster image issue, kinda unavoidable unless you plan for it during your initial designing. It's got a lot to do with your resolution.

Basically, The first 3 frames are fine because they haven't hit the distortion threshold. You always have some degree (literally) of rotation (which changes in each scenario) that your image can be rotated before Photoshop/your GPU is forced to 'generalize' the new angles, and use as many 'steps' as possible to look smoother.

You're getting that staircase effect because your asking RASTER pixels to arrange to a new curvature. In a vector program like Illustrator, this almost never happens.

As an experiment in PS, make a perfect square using the Marquee tool and just paint bucket it any color, do not use the Shape tool.... now little by little, grab a corner and slowly spin it. See the edges?

TL;DR, welcome to raster :)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely improve this by increasing the scale in Photoshop first before rotating it. See the example below. I grabbed this from your artwork.

**You will see that the larger you scale it the better it is at fixing your problem.**

This is using default Photoshop settings but if you mess with the settings you might find different results.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Simple Trick Just press shift while doing any transformation